# Как отобразить данные правила сборки в .pro файле

Tags: c++, opencv, qtcreator, компиляция, библиотеки

Я собрал opencv, написал файл для теста, через терминал этот файл собирается с помощью команды

```
g++ main.cpp -o output `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

Но когда я пытаюсь сделать тоже самое в qt creator, он не видит необходимых библиотек
Вот что я написал в pro файле

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
LIBS += -pthread

INCLUDEPATH += I-/usr/include/opencv4
LIBS += `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

Что нужно написать в pro файле, чтоб файл компилировался в qt creator тоже

Comment: а ещё в `INCLUDEPATH` опечатка...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`qmake` сам [умеет](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html#configuration-features) `pkg-config`:

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv4
```